# Media query en función del navegador?

Tags: sql, firefox, chrome

Por qué no me funciona la media query para controlar el alto de la pantalla en chrome pero en firefox si??

Tengo diferentes queries y tengo solo una que me controla el alto de la pantalla y es la que no me funciona en Chrome pero sí en todos los demás navegadores. No entiendo porqué :/

Código que tengo:

```
@media (max-height: 768px){ 
    /* alto portatil */

}
```

Esta es la única media query no me reconoce Chrome, todas las demás sí.

Tengo las siguientes etiquetas metas:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
```

Versión google chrome :  87.0.4280.88

Comment: ¿De qué manera no te funciona? ¿No se está aplicando en pantallas pequeñas o sí se aplica en pantallas más grandes?

Comment: @PabloLozano la media querie funciona, lo único que Chrome no la reconoce, todas las demás sí a excepción de Google Chrome, me funciona en Opera, Firerox y Edge